# Accessing specific data from JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to access a "minionsKilled" value in a JSON array.

The JSON looks like this:

[image]

And this is the code I have been trying:

```html
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'my_url.php',
        success: function(data){
            alert(JSON[data.matches[0].participants[0].stats.minionsKilled]);
        }
    });
```

But the value being returned is "undefined".

Any reason for this?

I've been at it for hours and can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data type is already set to "JSON", you wouldn't need to worry about using `JSON`.  Not to mention, there is no such thing as `JSON[]`.

You can just reference the object using

```
data.matches[0].participants[0].stats.minionsKilled
```

In addition, since you are using the Ajax method asynchronously and expecting JSON, why not use:

```
$.getJSON('my_url.php', function(data) {
  alert(data.matches[0].participants[0].stats.minionsKilled);
})
```

`$.getJSON` is an easier alias to `$.ajax({dataType: 'json'})`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
alert(data.JSON.matches[0].participants[0].stats.minionsKilled);
```

or if JSON in your image is just a kind of json indicator from the debugger you use maybe just

```
alert(data.matches[0].participants[0].stats.minionsKilled);
```